# Razorpay create and apply payments directly from server side without front end

Tags: razorpay

I am trying to integrate razorpay in my java application. it is completely backed and driven application. could someone help me with an api to create a payment method directly from backend apply payment so that it can generate a payment id and signature. i have gone trough the razor pay api documentation(https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/#fetch-a-payment) but i couldn't find anything that suits my functionaity.